# ipython script.py --matplotlib not working

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

I recently reinstalled Anaconda to get Python 3.6 and now figure generating code that always worked before fails. The plot window remains empty and the circle spins forever.  Example command:

```
ipython plot_eg.py --matplotlib
```

Script content:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([10.1, 9.2, 7.6, 5.4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
s.plot()
input('Enter to end:')
```

Or:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [10.1, 9.2, 7.6, 5.4])
input('Enter to end:')
```

Both snippets work fine in the IPython console but not when run as scripts. I have tried restarting, reinstalling, installing from Continuum (instead of miniconda) and using the Anaconda prompt. I am running Windows 10 on an somewhat old ASUS. The only other big change I have made recently was installing bash on Windows. Has something changed with how IPython works? Or maybe I have screwed up my system somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Because the question is not very accurate at describing the system in use, I don't know what exactly did work previously. I can just tell you one way of how it will work now.

1. Your script should use `pyplot.show()` to show the plot.
2. You should not use `--matplotlib` when running the script with IPython from the command promt.

Script (`script.py`):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series([10.1, 9.2, 7.6, 5.4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
s.plot()
plt.show()
```

Command call:

```
> ipython script.py
```

or simply use python

```
> python script.py
```